# Project reactor publishers initialisation taking time for first time initialisation

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive

I recently explored project reactor library and trying to use it for my use case where I have a list of tasks and some tasks are dependent on the execution of other tasks and some tasks can execute in parallel for the sake of performance. The execution order looks in form of directed acyclic graph. Below is the POC code for that:

```
public class ReactorPOC {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //First time executing mono is taking long time
        run();

        //All subsequent executions not excess time
        run();
        run();
    }

    public static void run() {
        try {
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
            Long st = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Publisher one = getTask(60, "one", executorService, st).cache();
            Publisher two = getTask(60, "two", executorService, st).cache();
            Publisher three = getTask(60, "three", executorService, st).cache();
            Publisher four = getTask(60, "four", executorService, st).cache();
            Publisher eight = getTask(60, "eight", executorService, st).cache();
            Publisher five = getTask(60, "five", executorService, st).cache();
            Publisher six = getTask(60, "six", executorService, st).cache();
            Publisher seven = getTask(60, "seven", executorService, st).cache();
            three = Flux.concat(Flux.merge(one, two), three);
            five = Flux.concat(Flux.merge(three, four, eight), five);
            six = Flux.concat(five, six);
            seven = Flux.concat(five, seven);
            Flux last = Flux.merge(one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight);
            last.blockLast();
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - st);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    static Mono getTask(int sleep, String task, ExecutorService executorService, long st) {
        return Mono.just(task).doOnSubscribe( i -> {
            System.out.println("Starting " + task + " at " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - st));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleep);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Ending " + task + " at " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - st));
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executorService));
    }

}
```

This is working as expected in terms of order of execution. But I have 2 doubts:

1. I have executed the graphical execution 3 times (calling 3 times from main function). The first time, it is taking around 1200 millisecs which is too long and for all the next executions, its taking around 250 millisecs which is the expected time it should take. I am trying to understand why it is taking so long the first time.
2. If any of the tasks breaks, I want to have a way to throw exception and not proceed further in the execution order. Is there any way to do that? I have a way I thought of where I will keep a shared object and will set a field with error and all the next tasks will look at this field first and then decide not to execute that task. I wanted to check if there is a better way of doing this.

Please help in clarifying the above two queries.

Also, I am new to this library and the whole reactive paradigm. So, if there are any inputs/suggestions on the above code, it would be great.

Thanks :)

Comment: I ran your code and I don't see any particularly evident dilation in the execution of any of the tasks.

Comment: I just ran it again and the output printed at the end of try block in run() gave 1342, 254, 244 ms respectively for the 3 calls on run(). The first execution took 1342 ms which is weird compared to the next 2 executions which took around 250ms. Did it not take that long when you run the above code?

Comment: The whole thing takes 437, 248 and 257 at the end of the try block for me.

Comment: Oh, that’s strange. But  anyway, even for you, if you run this multiple times, the first one takes more time compared to the next executions, but yeah not as high as it is for me though. So, looking to find reason for same since the application where I’ll use it is latency sensitive (just trying to make sure even the very first execution is quick :) )

Comment: you shouldn't need to use `.cache()` in this arrangement. if I'm not mistaken, if you assigned _all_ Monos to a distinct variable name, you wouldn't use a task variable twice, which indicates cache isn't necessary.

Comment: We can avoid .cache() for some tasks but not for all. For example, task 5 is dependency for both 6 and 7, so to not execute it twice, we need to cache it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I can see from running with AsyncProfiler and looking at a flame graph, it seems to be purely a factor of class loading.

the code could be improved, notably to remove caching and to avoid blocking inside the `doOnSubscribe` (which is a code smell), but it doesn't change the deal very much.

to better demonstrate, I've copy-pasted the `run()` method as `run2()` and have the `main` execute `run1()` then `run2()` (which are the exact same code). we can then observe that `run1()` always take more time, and the difference lies in class loading:

[image: run1 then run2]

if we launch `run2()` first, it becomes the one prominent in the flame graph with classloading delays:

[image]

Comment: Why is doOnSubscribe considered code smell and what alternative do you suggest to use? Also, do you have any pointers on point 2?